# How to find the version of an Ubuntu machine remotely?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have more than 60 to 80 systems running Ubuntu. Some of them are with version 8.04 and some of them are with latest version 10.10. Now we are in the process of upgrading all older Ubuntu version to a newer version. It is difficult to switch on every Ubuntu system and taking notes of older Ubuntu version and then upgrade. I have IP addresses of all these machines in a text a file. So I am looking for a simple bash script which will automate the task. I am expecting the output would look like this:

172.29.34.40 ubuntu 10.04
172.29.34.41 ubuntu 8.04
172.29.34.42 ubuntu 8.10

and so on.. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can get the Ubuntu version using

```
$ lsb_release -s -d
Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS
```

If you want to automate that, write a Bash script that reads list of hosts from stdin and executes the command over SSH. Something like

```
#!/bin/bash
while read host; do
   echo -n "$host: "
   ssh "$host" lsb_release -s -d < /dev/null
done
```

If you have one common user account on all the machines you want to connect to then this should be what you are looking for

```
#!/bin/bash
RUSER="username"
while read host; do
   echo -n "$host: "
   ssh "$RUSER@$host" lsb_release -s -d < /dev/null
done
```

Save it as versions.sh, remembering to make it executable (`chmod a+x versions.sh`), and execute

```
$ versions.sh < ips.txt
```

Comment: I want the output for all the 80 systems running ubuntu by executing single command or by simple script.I know to find the ubuntu version in a single machine.

Comment: I was already updating my answer when you posted the comment. Hope that helps.

Comment: btw, *$ip* may contain `user@host` information.

Comment: Yes, it can be anything accepted by ssh, as long as it's space separated.

Comment: Do you want me to make it as bash script?And $IP should contain ip addresses of all the machines right?

Comment: Updated with a complete Bash script that reads from a file (each host should be in a separate line).

Comment: Suppose if one of the system is down will it skip automatically and brings the ubuntu version of another system?

Comment: That while-loop will only iterate once, because ssh will read up the rest of stdin. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089

Comment: @geirha Updated, just run ssh in a subshell.

Comment: @Adam Byrtek, well the subshell is unnecessary, it's the redirection that makes the difference.

Comment: @geirha Agreed. That was long thread. I guess next time I should test the script before posting.

Comment: How ever it is very slow..Any way to speed up?

Comment: Fast and easy +1

Answer (score 3):

Assuming they are running SSH servers, you could try to guess Ubuntu versions based on the package version of SSH:

```
$ nc IP.IP.IP.IP 22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu5
Ctrl-C
```

Current versions of openssh are listed in Launchpad https://launchpad.net/distros/ubuntu/+source/openssh:

```
openssh | 1:4.2p1-7ubuntu3.5 | dapper-updates/main
openssh | 1:4.7p1-8ubuntu3   | hardy-updates/main
openssh | 1:5.1p1-6ubuntu2   | karmic/main
openssh | 1:5.3p1-3ubuntu6   | lucid-updates/main
openssh | 1:5.5p1-4ubuntu5   | maverick-updates/main
openssh | 1:5.8p1-1ubuntu2   | natty/main
```

So in my above example, `5.5p1` with a Debian version of `-4ubuntu5` looks to be an Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick system.

Some servers may have "DebianBanner no" in their `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, but the upstream version of OpenSSH is still visible which is sufficient to identify the system still (each release of Ubuntu so far has a different upstream version of OpenSSH).

Comment: I like this - this is potentially the least labour-intensive solution. It does not require you to set up anything on the 80 hosts.