# Testing multiple desktops simultaniously

Tags: 14.04, performance, testing, benchmarks

Our college is installing new ubuntu installed systems for our lab.They want to test the performance of the systems.I googled some benchmarking tools but we have 250 systems to test,is there a easy way other than installing benchmarking tool in each systems and running them??

Comment: Benchmarking is an artform in itself....thus this task is not necessarily as "easy" as you might believe to get rational results that really mean something.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't just benchmarking the systems, it's just basically how you maintain each machine. How, for example, would you make them all install the same package or remove one, or to install a specific update ahead of an automated upgrade and reboot?

There are tools like Landscape (needs a support subscription with Canonical) that makes this side of things a lot easier.

Other than that, I would start out making sure every machine has an admin user with a specific SSH key installed. You could start with one machine and clone that onto all the others. Once you have that you could [use something like `clusterssh`](https://askubuntu.com/a/34820/449) to address a whole load of computers and run the same on each:

```
cssh -a '/usr/bin/benchmark' admin@host1 admin@host2 admin@host3 admin@host4
```

If you don't need the long-term installs, you could just magic up a LiveUSB that autoloads your benchmark and sends it off to a central server. Make a few copies and just batch that around the network. Or the same with PXE netboot. All options.

Comment: What if all computers have same password do i need to enter password for each systems or only once?